# Android ADT Bundle for MAC content assist not work

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, eclipse-adt

I've installed the last version available for the download from the developer.android.com website of the Android ADT Bundle for MAC. It includes the essential Android SDK components and a version of the Eclipse IDE with built-in ADT (Android Developer Tools).
All seems to works fine except the content assist.
I'm not able to understand how to show the suggestion while i'm writing code. I've searched and tried different suggestion find over the net but not works at all!
For example:
Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced. Make sure “Java Proposals” is ticked.
I've also tried to select all without results.
Can you help me, please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you change key binding ? By ctrl+space bar invoke spotlight (in right top), try to change it. If nothing appear with this new key binding try to download once again ... good luck :)

Comment: Thanks @theMouk for your reply. Yes appear the spotlight but i'm not sure to understand how to change it. Perhaps i'm in error but when i use xCode and write a class method, it's enough write the first letter and the content assist show the complete signature of this. Is could possibile also with eclipse? if i'm writing for example public void onC..... no suggestion appear. i missing something?? Thanks

Comment: it's strange ... Change your content asset key binding in eclipse in Preferences->general->keys. Search with filter search bar : "Content Assist". For example I changed mine by cmd+enter, I find it faster.